# How to change url path and have https:// instad of http?

Tags: .htaccess, url, https, url-rewriting

Im trying to change my url path from:

```
example.com/path/index.php
```

or

```
http://example.com/path/index.php
```

to

```
https://example.com/
```

-

and from

```
www.example.com/path/index.php
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/path/index.php
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/path/index.php
```

This is what I have so far, it works fine for the https:// part but not the changing my url path

.htaccess file

```
#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


#Change to / instead of /path/index.php (Doesn't work.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ path/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment yet so I ask it here:

Your question / requirement will end up with serving requests in 2 dommain with www and domain w/o www:

```
example.com/path/index.php
```

or

```
http://example.com/path/index.php
```

to

```
https://example.com/
```

which return to the landing page --- no rediction to www.example.com, is this right?

and from

```
www.example.com/path/index.php
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/path/index.php
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/path/index.php
```

simply to force https enabled?

If it's true, then your code below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

is adding www to the host and not related to the requirement/question you post. Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: I apologize for that, yes. I was doing it so it redirects everything to www. and I pasted in the wrong code (the www. version) it doesn't really matter. My main point is to force https and change the url path/ lading page.